# memset with Swift 5.2

Tags: swift, xcode, memset

Sometimes I need to clear a part of a byte array to zero. With a for loop this is slow. Much faster is using the memset() function. I have the following code which will clear elements 200 to 299 of the array "a".

```
var a: [UInt8] = [UInt8](repeating: 1, count: 1000) // a[0..999] set to 1
start = 200
length = 100
memset(&a + start, 0, length) // a[100..199] set to 0
```

This worked well until Swift 5.2 with Xcode 11.4 came out. Now it works, too, but a warning appears:

Inout expression creates a temporary pointer, but argument #1 should be a pointer that outlives the call to '+'

How can this made, to have no warning.? Andybody has an idea?

Some more explanations is whows in Xcode:

1. Implicit argument conversion from '[UInt8]' to 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' produces a pointer valid only for the duration of the call to '+'
2. Use the 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined scope

I do not understand, what this means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint to use `withUnsafeMutableBytes` is exactly what you should follow:

```
a.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr in
    _ = memset(ptr.baseAddress! + start, 0, length)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I got a new warning: Result of call to 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is unused. So I added an underline: _ = a.withUnsafeMutableBytes...

Comment: Oops, yeah, thanks for the hint. It's actually better to hide the return value inside the closure, I've updated the answer